# Press enter on click with database connection

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, enter

I am trying to allow my user to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to Log In. However, I have got a database connection with all sorts of validation. Is it possible to integrate the code within what I have already got.

I have been working on this for hours now and its driving me mad. I have got it working without the database connection but I need it to work with my existing code.

Could someone please tell me how I can do this?

This is the code that I have already got:

```
    Try
        Dim objconnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Cara\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Online Portal Solutions\Online Portal Solutions\Online Portal Solutions Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
        objconnection.Open()
        Dim SelectStmt As String = "SELECT * FROM [1InnospecLogIn] WHERE Username='" & txt_cusername.Text & "' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS AND Password='" & txt_cpassword.Text & "' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS ;"
        Dim objcommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(SelectStmt, objconnection)
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = objcommand.ExecuteReader

        If reader.Read Then
            If txt_cpassword.Text <> reader("Password").ToString And txt_cusername.Text <> reader("Username").ToString Then
                frm_2custhome.Show()
                Me.Hide()
                txt_cusername.Text = ""
                txt_cpassword.Text = ""
                combocustomer.SelectedIndex = -1
                txt_cusername.Select()
            End If
        Else
            Static count As Integer = 0
            Dim prompt As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid credentials.", "Login Error",
                                                         MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
            Select Case prompt
                Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Retry
                    txt_cusername.Text = ""
                    txt_cpassword.Text = ""
                    combocustomer.SelectedIndex = -1
                    txt_cusername.Select()
                    count += 1
                    If count = 3 Then
                        MessageBox.Show("High value of failed login attempts." & vbCrLf & "Application will be terminated for security reasons.", "Error",
                                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
                        End
                    End If
                Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
                    Application.Exit()
            End Select
        End If

        objconnection.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to change your if condition :

```
If txt_cpassword.Text <> reader("Password").ToString And txt_cusername.Text <> reader("Username").ToString Then
```

Change it to

```
If txt_cpassword.Text = reader("Password").ToString And txt_cusername.Text = reader("Username").ToString Then
```

And according to me your else portion will come in inner if condition.Then your question of how to provide this on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. First keep your existing code in a sub routine or a function and call it when require. Now, Get the KeyDown event of the textbox and call that function on enter key. Have a look,

```
 Private Sub txtUserName_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtUserName.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        authenticate()  ' Function containing that code.
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: The code that you provided in your question keep that one in a function. Then go to to the Design View of your form -> Select the textbox on which you want the facility of enter -> go to property window select event tab -> Double click on KeyDown event. Call that authentication function from there using my above given code.